# Мультилайновый QTabWidget

Tags: ui, qt4

Как можно сделать таб со вкладками, которые располагаются в несколько рядов?[image: Мультилайновый таб]

На основе `QTabWidget` или другого виджета.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попробовал использовать `QStackedWidget` для содержимого и несколько рядов `QTabBar` для вкладок.

Answer (score 1):

Встроенного решения нет, всё придётся делать вручную.

Учтите, что табы в несколько строк нынче считаются дурным тоном. Если у вас много вкладок, лучше расположить заголовки в виде списка или дерева слева, а содержимое, соответствующее выбранному пункту, показывать справа. В многострочных вкладках слишком просто заблудиться, потому что строки меняются положением (активный таб должен быть на нижней строке).

Это тем более актуально для диалогов настроек. Практически во всех современных приложениях в сложных диалогах с настройками избавляюстя от табов. Что где-то в Windows остаются подобные диалоги — это наследие царского режима, а не образец для подражания.